# Swift UiButton how to left align the title?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton created programmatically but can't find a way to left align the title.

This does nothing:

```
button.setTitle("DESCRIPTION", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this one

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Answer (score 0):

For left side aligment:

```
buttonItem.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

For right side aligment:

```
buttonLogout.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
```

and bydefault alignment for button title is center.